# Do logic-level MOSFETs achieve galvanic isolation?

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, isolation

I tried using transistors (TIP122) before in my Arduino circuits to run motors and solenoids, but the analog input from a sensor would shift by many ADC values.

To sort that out I chose to use relay modules, which achieved galvanic isolation but interference in analog signals stayed because there are coils involved.

To sort it out I tried using SSRs, but even those SSRs rated for DC failed to function, leading me to believe an SSR can only switch AC.

So my current refuge is the idea of using logic-level MOSFETs. Will logic-level MOSFETs save effect of motors and solenoid valves on ADC?

Below is how I plan to link the logic-level MOSFET:

[image]

Comment: why are you not asking about the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I cannot give you a complete answer because many of the needed details are missing. Your frizzy picture is next to useless, a real annotated schematic showing all power and ground connections would be a big help. Showing the supply voltages is important.  Be sure it also has the analog connections and links to "Technical" information on the hardware devices. If I were to take a SWAG it appears your power supply is not adequate or the impedance of the power circuit especially ground is causing problems.

Comment: This seems like an ideal case for a solid state relay. Which SSR did you use that failed? Did you protect the SSR with a diode and fuse?

Comment: @C.Dunn This is the one https://robu.in/product/8-channel-3-24v-relay-module-solid-state-high-level-ssr-dc-control-dc-with-resistive-fuse/ . Somehow, no matter whether high or low, the ends were always connected.

Comment: @Gil I agree details are wanting for analysis of my problem, but for that I'll post a proper question soon. I just wanted clarification on what I could expect with the FET I am using.

Comment: Galvanic isolation won’t necessarily save you from noise and transients. Capacitive and inductive coupling can still ruin your day. Consider the average modern vehicle has lots of electronics with analog sensors and no galvanic isolation even in spite of the ignition system.

Comment: @Kartman yeah, that has been my experience. Right now since the noise with the Relay module is predictable, I just mathematically subtract it. But there must be some way to eliminate noise. How do the folks on USS Discovery do it who need intergalactic instruments highly accurate and dependable?

Comment: The real world is full of noise - you can't eliminate it. You can, however, take steps to minimise it and filter it. Any input to a computing system should be filtered - the old adage 'garbage in, garbage out' applies. Activating the relay itself should not affect the ADC, if it is, then you've got wiring or circuit issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation): -

> Galvanic isolation is used where two or more electric circuits must
> communicate, but their grounds may be at different potentials. It is
> an effective method of breaking ground loops by preventing unwanted
> current from flowing between two units sharing a ground conductor.

> *Do Logic Level MOSFETs achieve galvanic isolation?*

The MOSFET source pin is common to both input circuitry and output circuitry therefore, from the above Wikipedia definition, there is no galvanic isolation because the source connection is a common ground for both circuits.

Answer (score 1):

No, FETs don't provide galvanic isolation.